# How is CountDownTimer accessing UI inside OnTick method?

Tags: android, layout, countdowntimer

How `CountDownTimer` is accessing UI inside `onTick` method?

```
(new CountDownTimer(10000,1000){

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvLCD);
        tv.setText(Long.toString(millisUntilFinished));
    }           
}).start();
```

Comment: What do you mean by how? It's anonymous inner class, it has access to activity fields.

Comment: I wanted to access UI from Thread but I couldn't & I found CountDownTimer class which is easly get access to UI elements inside onTick method. It is counting down (I think using a thread) and easly accessing to UI. I wonder how...

Comment: Like @damluar said, it is an anonymous inner class: it can access all Activity fields AND methods (so `findViewById` works).

Comment: It works the same way as AsyncTask, having one method to execute in UI thread

Comment: It is working fine ...what is your problem????

Comment: @Femi, you are right the object that is created from `CountDownTime` is inside the Activity class but if it is running in other thread when `start()` method triggered it can't get access to UI elements can it? Is there any tutorial which is showing the thread inside an activity and can easily UI elements from `run()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get access to UI from thread by [`Activity.runOnUiTread()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29), [`View.post()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29), [`View.postDelayed()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) or via [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html). `CountDownTimer` uses `Handler` for this purpose ([source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1/android/os/CountDownTimer.java#109)).

Read [this article](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2009/05/painless-threading.html) for understanding how to use all of these methods.

Comment: I saw your links. After reading them I came to know that Countdown timer uses a handler but does not spawn a new thread. So that means, the countdown is not happening in a separate thread. Then why use a HANDLER? The purpose of handler is to act as a medium between a thread and a Ui thread.

Comment: The link to the article is broken.

Comment: @Ashwin, the purpose of the handler is not to act as medium between a thread and a UI thread, one of the purposes is to execute code on different thread than the current one. CountDownTimer doesn't necessarily use the ui thread, read my answer for better explanation.

Answer (score 8):

From the links( [GreCode - Handler](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1/android/os/CountDownTimer.java) ) in the answer given by @Sergey Glotov, it is clear that **countdown timer does not use a seperate thread** at all. That is the reason you are able to access the all the UI elements. I don't know why they have used a handler. But it does not spawn a new thread. It runs on the UI thread itself.

Comment: The documentation doesn't actually say anything about this though, so I'd consider that an implementation detail and dangerous to rely on.  AsyncTask explicitly calls out the functions that are run on the UI thread, so if something doesn't say that I would hedge my bets and just use runOnUiThread().

Answer (score 2):

`CountDownTimer` does NOT have any mechanism to access UI inside onTick method.
More importantly, from the source code, you can see that internally it uses an handler that is taken at object creation. So **it runs on the Thread where the timer was created.**

The question is ill-posed, in your case i suppose you can access those views because probably you create the `CountDownTimer` as anonymous class on an activity. And if you were lucky enough, this was done on the UI thread.