# android countdown force to close error

Tags: android

I have this code:

```
import android.app.Activity;     
import android.os.Bundle;     
import android.os.CountDownTimer;     
import android.widget.TextView;       

 public class MActivity extends Activity {      

 TextView start;    

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    

      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
      setContentView(R.layout.main);    

      start = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.start_me);    

        CountDownTimer aCounter = new CountDownTimer(100000 , 1000) {    
              public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {    
                  start.setText("Remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);    
              }    

                public void onFinish() {    
                    start.setText("Finished");     
                }     
             };      
           aCounter.start();     
   }     
 }
```

But when I run it, it crashes with force to close error. Can you help me that where can be the problem?

Comment: is R.id.start_me declared in R.layout.main?

Comment: What exceptions are shown in LogCat? This will usually lead you to see what is wrong. It could be a null pointer error or maybe you need to use runOnUiThread().

Comment: thread exiting with uncaught exception
Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo
AndroidRuntime(9668):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage

Comment: thread exiting with uncaught exception
Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo
AndroidRuntime(9668):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage these are 3 out of 11 exception errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CountDownTimer` is not running on the UI Thread and therefore will throw an fatal exception when it tries to modify something that belongs to the UI.

[How is CountDownTimer accessing UI inside OnTick method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354740/how-is-countdowntimer-accessing-ui-inside-ontick-method)

EDIT:

Seems like @blackbelt commenter was right. I went ahead and made an android project and your code works just fine (Android 2.3.3).

Maybe you'd care to give us the exception? Like an excerpt from your logcat?

Comment: android doc stays differently: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Comment: So how should I change it if I want it to show these changes as a textview?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/start_me"
    android:text="Time: "
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />


</LinearLayout> my main.xml in like this. so what can be the problem?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any problem there... I'd suggest to start a new project from scratch. I think there might be a problem in your manifest.xml file...