# CountDownTimer for quiz can't be accessed how I need it to be

Tags: java, android, timer, countdowntimer

I am writing a small math's quiz with 10 questions per level. I'm trying to write a 10 second timer which has the following functions:

- Moves to the next question when it runs out and restarts the timer
- Restarts when a question is entered

My issue is that regardless of how I write this code, I cannot access the timer from both the "onFinish()" function as well as the rest of the program. such as "onCorrect()" I need to be able to cancel and restart an existing timer initialised in "onCreate()" however I can't then access that timer through a MyCountDownTimer class or function (I've tried using both to no avail.)

My code is below with comments to show where I need the timers to work.

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


import java.util.Random;


public class Level2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    int score = 0;
    int q = 1;
    TextView value;
    TextView q_num;
    TextView timer_label = findViewById(R.id.Timer);

    /*public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
        TextView timer_label = findViewById(R.id.Timer);
        public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
            super(startTime, interval);
        }


        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            onDone();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            int temp = (int)millisUntilFinished/1000;
            //do what ever You want
            timer_label.setText(String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.timer_string),String.valueOf(temp)));


        }
    }
    @Override

     */
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_level2);


        q = 1;
        //MyCountDownTimer t = new MyCountDownTimer(11000,1000);

        Button b1 = findViewById(R.id.option1);
        Button b2 = findViewById(R.id.option2);
        Button b3 = findViewById(R.id.option3);
        Button b4 = findViewById(R.id.option4);

        Random first = new Random();
        int upperbound = 100;
        int random_id = first.nextInt(upperbound);

        selectData(random_id);


        //
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); //bellow setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.action_layout);
        //Gives action bar style

        value = findViewById(R.id.score_value);
        q_num = findViewById(R.id.question_number);


        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                String ans = (String) b1.getText();
                onCheck(ans,score);
            }
        });
        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                String ans = (String) b2.getText();
                onCheck(ans,score);
            }
        });
        b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                String ans = (String) b3.getText();
                onCheck(ans,score);
            }
        });
        b4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                String ans = (String) b4.getText();
                onCheck(ans,score);
            }
        });


    }



    public void onCheck(String ans, int score) {
        TextView ans_data = findViewById(R.id.answer_data);
        String correct = (String) ans_data.getText();
        if (ans.contains(correct)) {
            onCorrect(score);
        }
        else{

            onWrong();
        }
    }


    public void onCorrect(int temp){
        //t.cancel()
        //t.start()
        temp++;
        score = temp;
        q++;
        if(q >= 11){
            if(score >2){
                complete(score);
            }
            else{
                Intent i = new Intent(Level2.this, ne.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
        value.setText(String.valueOf(score));
        q_num.setText(String.valueOf(q));
        Random first = new Random();
        int upperbound = 100;
        int random_id = first.nextInt(upperbound);
        selectData(random_id);
    }

    public void onDone(){
        //t.start()
        q++;
        if(q>=11){
            if(score >2){
                complete(score);
            }
            else{
                Intent i = new Intent(Level2.this, ne.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
        else{
            q_num.setText(String.valueOf(q));
            Random first = new Random();
            int upperbound = 100;
            int random_id = first.nextInt(upperbound);
            selectData(random_id);
        }
    }

    public void onWrong(){
        //t.cancel()
        //t.start
        q++;
        if(q>=11){
            if(score >2){
                complete(score);
            }
            else{
                Intent i = new Intent(Level2.this, ne.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
        else{
            q_num.setText(String.valueOf(q));
            Random first = new Random();
            int upperbound = 100;
            int random_id = first.nextInt(upperbound);
            selectData(random_id);
        }
```

For reference;

- onCheck() checks if the answer is right
- onCorrect() is right
- onWrong() is wrong
- onDone() is when the timer runs out

The root of my issue is that I cannot put t into onDone as it's called by the MyCountDownTimer class which doesn't have access to the t called in onCreate.

Comment: Accessing UI elements directly in `onTick` is bad, as GUI access should only be done from main Thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354740/how-is-countdowntimer-accessing-ui-inside-ontick-method

Answer (score 0):

Declare MyCountDownTimer t outside of onCreate() as a global variable.